# XML 2 Array Markup in Text Issue

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm struggeling with the following problem. I try to convert an xml document to an array in PHP, which is working fine so far. But I do have some special elements which contain text with markup in it. The elements looks something like this:

```
<section>
    <name>sectionname</name>
    <subsection>
        <subsectionname>one</subsectionname>
        <element>
            <text>some text <xref>a</xref>, <xref>b</xref>, <xref>c</xref></text>
        </element>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
        <subsectionname>two</subsectionname>
        <element>
            <text>some text <xref>a</xref>, <xref>b</xref>, <xref>c</xref></text>
        </element>
    </subsection>
</section>
```

I tried to work with simplexml in the first place:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

but this will return an element containing "some text , , and some more" without the content of xref. What I actually want is the whole text "some text a, b, c and some more", but I am afraid I do not know how to achieve this.
And I already gave DOMDocument a shot, but had problems with the whole thing there as it is a quite complex xml.

Any ideas how I could receive what I want?

EDIT: I've added a more complex example of the xml. As you can see I would need to traverse over sections, then subsections and in there, the elements with markup and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with SimpleXML is that it tends to group text nodes into 1 lump.  To be able to get the properly split text you tend to have to use DOMDocument.

As you can see this loads the document and then uses XPath to find the Element/Text nodes ( this is just to get to the right point - you can use `getElementsByTagName()` if you wish).  Then inside that node it again uses XPath to find all of the text nodes (using `descendant::text()`) which will then fetch each piece of text in sequence from `<text>` node in the document.

For each Text node this creates a blank `$text` string and adds the content to it in the loop and then displays it...

```
$data = '<section>
    <name>sectionname</name>
    <subsection>
        <subsectionname>one</subsectionname>
        <element>
            <text>some text <xref>a</xref>, <xref>b</xref>, <xref>c</xref></text>
        </element>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
        <subsectionname>two</subsectionname>
        <element>
            <text>some text <xref>a</xref>, <xref>b</xref>, <xref>c</xref>d</text>
        </element>
    </subsection>
</section>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($data);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ( $xp->query("//element/text") as $element ) {
    $text = '';
    foreach ( $xp->query("descendant::text()", $element) as $textNode )    {
        $text .= $textNode->textContent;
    }   
    echo $text.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This displays (I modified the second one to help)...

```
some text a, b, c
some text a, b, cd
```

**Edit:**

As ThW points out, using [`textContent`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) will fetch all of the text including the child nodes, so you can shorten the inner loop to

```
foreach ( $xp->query("//element/text") as $element ) {
    echo $element->textContent.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: `DOMNode::$textContent` returns the text content of all relevant descendants and will even resolve entities. So you can replace the inner loop with `$text = $element->textContent;` https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to use `DOMDocument` - if I understood the question correctly you could try like this ~ though as there is only a small snippet of XML this might be wide of the mark

```
<?php

    $strxml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <root>
            <element>
                <text>some text <xref>a</xref>, <xref>b</xref>, <xref>c</xref> and some more</text>
            </element>
            <element>
                <text>a banana <xref>FFF</xref>, <xref>GGG</xref>, <xref>ZZZ</xref> and some more bananas</text>
            </element>
        </root>';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML( $strxml );

    $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('element');
    $output=array();

    foreach( $col as $node )$output[]=$node->childNodes[1]->nodeValue;


    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $output, true ) );

?>
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => some text a, b, c and some more
    [1] => a banana FFF, GGG, ZZZ and some more bananas
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the simple example this is working great, but I still have difficulties when it gets more complex. I've updated my question with a more complex xml. My problem is the traversing over elements and then getting the desired data.